Have the results of any U.S. presidential election other than 2000, 2020 been widely disputed and litigated?
The results of two U.S. presidential elections in the last 24 years have been hotly contested and litigated:

The 2000 election was won by George W. Bush by just 537 votes in Florida. After attempts at a recount which some believed could flip the state to Al Gore and consequently hand him the presidency, the SCOTUS case Bush v. Gore ultimately gave it to Bush, with Gore conceding on December 13, 2000.

The 2020 election was claimed by Donald Trump to have been "stolen"; he maintains to this day that he is the legitimate winner. There were recount efforts such as those in Arizona and Georgia.


Both of the above elections had results widely disbelieved by the public and are still seen as controversial.
Are there any other U.S. elections similar to these two, in the sense that some of the following hold?

One of the candidates did not concede the election (at least for some time)
There was a substantial amount of litigation in an attempt to change the result of the election
There was widespread disbelief among the public as to who the rightful winner of the election was


I would write 'disbelieved by large parts of the public'. In both your examples I would say at least half of the people believe the results are exactly as they should be.

For what it's worth, those 2 cases are very different. In 2000, the result hinged entirely on Florida, which was won by 537 votes. A recount was legally required (although there may have been additional litigation and controversy beyond that). In 2020, Biden won by a substantial margin: at least 3 swing states would've had to flip to change the overall result, and that would've required at least around 40000 votes to tie or 60000 to flip (if my back-of-the-envelope maths is right).

"Both of the above elections had results widely disbelieved by the public and are still seen as controversial." – Is this actually true? I have the feeling that nobody except a small, but very loud and aggressive circle around Donald Trump actually believes this. I admit, in my personal circles, supporters of Donald Trump are pretty rare, but the ones that are, are in fact rather embarrassed about the fact that their preferred candidate is still peddling his conspiracy theories.

Should this be on [History.SE]?

@JörgWMittag not small, not small at all. Here's one source claiming 35% of the general US population and 65% of Republicans say they don't trust the 2020 election results. Here's another claiming 30%.

One I don't see here, but I don't have time to write a full answer: 1824, where the election went to the House of Representatives, and afterwards Andrew Jackson charged there had been a "corrupt bargain" involved in selecting John Quincy Adams.  (And of course, 1860 presidential election triggered the Civil War, but I wouldn't count that because it was a rejection of the elected president and his party, not a rejection of the validity of the election.)

Seems like a minimal amount of research should have turned up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_controversial_elections#United_States

I don't have 1960s post-election polls on hand, but that one is plausibly one that might meet some of the criteria in your list, and isn't super ancient  https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42084/was-jfks-1960-election-win-due-to-fraud

Apart from the obvious 1876 case, in 1800 36 contingent votes were held in the House of Representatives over a week to achieve a majority decision about who had won, while the 1856 election led to secession and civil war.

1876, Rutherford B. Hayes (R) v. Samuel J. Tilden (D)
The South had much voter intimidation against Black people and Republicans, with at least 150 people outright murdered.
Three states: Florida (4 EV), Louisiana (8 EV), and South Carolina (7 EV), had different factions of the state government submitted conflicting certificates saying who won the election in their state.  Meanwhile, in Oregon, one Republican Elector was disqualified for being a Postmaster (thus a "person holding an office of trust or profit under the United States"), and the state governor appointed a Democrat in his place.  So, there were a total of 20 Electors in dispute.
When Congress (then divided with a Democrat House and Republican Senate) met to count the votes, they couldn't agree on how to count the disputed states, so they formed a special 15-member Electoral Commission to settle the result.  The commission was intended to consist of 7 members of each major party plus one "independent", David Davis, then a Supreme Court Justice.  But before the commission met, the Illinois Legislature elected Davis to the Senate, and David resigned his position in order to take his Senate seat.  He was replaced with Justice Joseph Bradley, a republican.
On March 2, 1877 (115 days after the general election, and only 2 days before Inaguaration Day), the commission decided 8-7, completely along party lines, to award all 20 disputed Electoral Votes to Hayes, and thus Hayes "won" the election by a single vote, 185-184.
Some Democrats vocally complained that Tilden had been cheated, and threatened to filibuster the election results.  But Hayes and his supporters proposed a compromise whose terms included the U.S. would withdraw the remaining military occupation units from the South, in exchange for the Southern states pinky-promising to be nice to their Black populations.

The 1824 election was known as the Corrupt Bargain. With four candidates (John Quincy Adams, Andrew Jackson, William Crawford, and Henry Clay) splitting the Electoral College, none of them won a majority. According to the Twelfth Amendment, the House gets to vote amongst themselves between the top three candidates. Clay was very influential in the House at the time and gave his support to Adams in exchange for being made Secretary of State. Adams was made president, despite Jackson winning the most electoral votes and the popular vote. Clay was made Secretary of State and Jackson campaigned on the "Corrupt Bargain" claim for the next four years.

A reference to the election with supporting information is generally recommended.

1960
Nixon vs Kennedy. History has somewhat swallowed both men (Kennedy was assassinated in 1963 and Nixon resigned over the Watergate scandal). But before 2000, this was the most contentious of the 20th century.
This election was incredibly close. Kennedy won the popular vote by about 130,000 votes (68M+ were cast), and this was the narrowest election of the 20th century.
There was significant litigation in Hawaii due to the close margin and recount changing the result.

Similarly, in Hawaii, official results showed Nixon winning by a small margin of 141 votes, with the state being called for him early Wednesday morning. Acting Governor James Kealoha certified the Republican electors, and they cast Hawaii's three electoral votes for Nixon. However, clear discrepancies existed in the official electoral tabulations, and Democrats petitioned for a recount in Hawaii circuit court.[76] The court challenge was still ongoing at the time of the Electoral Count Act's safe harbor deadline, but Democratic electors still convened at the ʻIolani Palace on the constitutionally-mandated date of December 19 and cast their votes for Kennedy. The recount, completed before Christmas, resulted in Kennedy being declared winner by 115 votes. On December 30, the circuit court ruled that Hawaii's three electoral votes should go to Kennedy. It was decided that a new certificate was necessary, with only two days remaining before Congress convened on January 6, 1961, to count and certify the Electoral College votes.

Rather than litigate on, Nixon conceded and allowed the electors to elect Kennedy.

But it wasn’t close at all in terms of electoral votes? Kennedy would’ve still won without Hawaii.

@JonathanReez Yes, but Hawaii wasn't the only close state. In fact, California flipped to Nixon after a recount. Many states were very close on their vote counts and a small shift would have thrown it to Nixon.




Hillary Clinton: Trump is an ‘illegitimate president’

Hillary Clinton dismissed President Trump as an “illegitimate president” and suggested that “he knows” that he stole the 2016 presidential election in a CBS News interview to be aired Sunday.
...

That certainly seems to qualify as "not conceding the election".
Immediately after the election, there were efforts to blame Clinton's loss on "Russia! Russia! Russia!":
White House Confirms Pre-Election Warning to Russia Over Hacking
Election denial continued:
Clinton opens door to questioning legitimacy of 2016 election
And finally, almost half of Clinton voters believed the election was illegitimate:
74 Percent Call Election Legitimate, But With a Vast Partisan Divide: Poll:

Nearly three-quarters of Americans in a new ABC News/Washington Post poll accept Donald Trump’s election as legitimate -- but with a vast gap between his supporters and others that underscores the nation’s continued deep political divisions.

Almost half of Clinton's voters would be millions and millions of people.  That is certainly "widespread disbelief".
Edit:
Downvoting this kinda makes my point, doesn't it?
Invoking "Russia! Russia! Russia!" 8 years after the fact is how you try to make a claim that the 2016 election wasn't disputed?  That's downright risible.

https://www.politico.com/story/2016/11/clinton-concedes-to-trump-we-owe-him-an-open-mind-231118 But yeah there was apparently election meddling by Russia, as well as obstruction of justice by the Trump administration about that. So either way that was actually handled sub par.

Yeah, it's fun to just quote the (CNN!) clickbait headline, but the first para is  that she "said she “would not” rule out questioning the legitimacy of the 2016 election if Russian interference is deeper than currently known." So it was a rather conditional statement. (Not too unlike Trump's in the same election who said he would not recognize it as legit... if he lost.) Clinton also admitted that she had no legal mechanism to challenge the result, even if she was somehow right on her hunch.

Also, I personally dislike the polls that ask that Q using the word 'legitimate'. Because some interpret it as "allowed under the law" and some as "reasonable and acceptable"... both of which are in the dictionary as defs of 'legitimate'. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/legitimate

Did she concede?  Yes, the day after the election, stating publicly, "We owe him an open mind."  Was there excessive litigation?  Recounts were requested in 5 close states by Green Party candidate Jill Stein, no litigation that I'm aware of.  Was there widespread disbelief that the candidate had won?  Almost nobody disputed the election results, however, the extent of foreign interference and the intervention by FBI Director Comey were seen as unfairly prejudicial by most Democrats - that's your lack of legitimacy.  The election was not disputed.

"But yeah there was apparently election meddling by Russia, as well as obstruction of justice by the Trump administration about that" <- I don't see how that is borne out by the eventually-established facts. And the obstruction of justice did not regard meddling by Russia, it was obstruction by some people of Trump's campaign regarding the investigation.

"One of the candidates did not concede the election (at least for some time" - Day after, Clinton conceded. Arguing she didn't concede because she questioned the legitimacy and legality of surrounding events doesn't change the bald fact that she conceded, and quickly. Her concerns about the legality of Trump campaigns actions aren't wrong just because Mueller was obstructed. And even if they were wrong, she conceded.

It's hard to see how the downvotes prove your point.  You should probably remove that edit since that's the sort of thing people who don't have any actual point say.

The fact is that there was considerable Russian interference and meddling in the 2016 election, so her concerns over Trump being elected illegitimately were correct. https://www.pbs.org/newshour/show/inside-the-mueller-report-a-sophisticated-russian-interference-campaign Here's the report itself. https://www.justice.gov/archives/sco/file/1373816/dl Let's also not forget that Trump obstructed the investigation in many ways, including trying to get Mueller fired. Also, most of the real concern about the vote is she won the popular vote by 3 million, but then somehow lost the electoral vote.

@computercarguy Russia buying some ads or whatnot cannot possibly make elections illegitimate. Them directly sabotaging the vote process (by say stuffing ballot boxes) definitely could but this was never claimed to be true.

Downvoted because the first item in particular elides the timespan (nearly three years) between Clinton (A) immediately conceding the election and (B) complaining about its legitimacy to CBS. (Trump started complaining about the illegitimacy of the 2016 election months before election day and has never stopped complaining about it.)

Trump still argues he won the popular vote in 2016. He hasn't even conceded that.

Sorry, this doesn't meet the standard in the question. What litigation was there?

@JonathanReez, if there was enough electoral fraud found, even without it being direct ballot tampering, it could make the election illegitimate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_fraud What we don't know, because of the redaction of the Mueller report, is just how much interference Russia actually caused. We know that Trump specifically told Barr to do the redactions, so there's plenty of motive and opportunity to hide any facts saying if the election was truly illegitimate.

@computercarguy unless Russia directly influenced the voting sites in some way, it doesn't really matter.

@JonathanReez, then we should petition Biden to release the unredacted Mueller report to see just how much Russia did interfere and see if they did do direct tampering. According to the recent SCOTUS ruling, POTUS has immunity for any official act they perform, and exposing election fraud would be well within that purview.

The neat thing about unprosecuted obstruction is that the report can't contain what the obstructed details would be needed for.
